# AnyLogic - Excel output: delete spreadsheet before each simulation run?

Tags: excel, simulation, anylogic

After destroying my main agent I wrote a code `ExcelFile.setCellValue(...)` that puts parameters into an Excel.

My output function with excel works but only if I delete the whole workspace of each spreadsheet before every simulation run. Because I have a big number of sheets this is very exhausting. Is there a possibility to overwrite my output excel without deleting manually ever sheet after a simulation run? This would save me a ton of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it this way:

```
//--Clearing the file------------------
excelFileOutput.readFile();

for (int m=1;m<6;m++){ //for each sheet
    for (int i=0;i<15;i++){      //for each column  
        for (int j=2;j<50000;j++){   //for each row 
            excelFileOutput.clearCell(m,j,i);   
    }       
            
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Where do I have to put this code? Same place (in my case a function) where I wrote the code for exporting the data or in main class additional code?

Comment: I do this before writing the output at the end of the simulation. But it doesn't matter..you can do at the beginning also

Comment: Okay perfect. Thank you for the quick help! If I have a higher reputation I will mark your post as helpful.

Comment: glad it was useful. please feel free to accept as answer (I think this should be possible even with 0 zero reputation) and upvote.